# imprimir contenido en un html paralelo

Tags: javascript, html5

gracias de antemano...espero q me puedan ayudar el problema es el siguiente:

tengo un archivo html principal el cual esta asociado a un javascript y sus estilos correspondientes, el problema recae en que en el javascript se hace una serie de procesos y al final tengo una lista de resultados en forma de tabla(html5) la cual quiero imprimir en un div que se encuentra en otro archivo html difrente al principal, la cuestion como le puedo enviar esos resultados a la pagina secundaria

Comment: Puedes utilizar [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) para guardar esos resultados y luego acceder a ellos sin problema...

Answer (score 0):

No se si entiendo bien el caso, pero quizá pueda ser enviando la data como request del HTML principal al otro.

Me explico:
En el HTML1, en el codigo javascript, al final de los procesos podrías hacer una redirección simple al HTML2 y le pasas los datos como parametros GET (por URL); luego, en el HTML2, con Javascript optienes los parametros GET y llenas la tabla. No es la manera mas elegante de hacerlo, ni la mas optima, pero si la mas simple. Espero haber entendido lo que quieres intentar, saludos.

Comment: si te entendi lo habia pensado asi...es que estaba intentando obtener el id del div con el docuement.getElementByid(iddiv) y meterle los datos, pero me di cuenta q al hacer el document.get....me retornaba null por q en ese momento el div como tal no existe tal ves lo intente como dices :) gracias

Comment: Excelente, entonces solucionado :D